# Snychronise 2 pods in Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, quarkus

we have 2 pods running which has a method starting at the same time(has a scheduler annotation).
So we get a brutal race condition.
I don't see any way to prevent the race condition. Pessmistic Locking makes sense
within the same process. But we have 2 pods. I only see the way to have the one pod run a little bit later than the other pod. But I don't know if you can configure that some way.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Scheduled from your app and deploy a CronJob in Kubernetes which makes a REST call to your app.

Or, if you don’t want this solution, then use  [ShedLock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#cdi-integration) which also has support for Quarkus now.